# How to add a favorite function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

First time asking here so be patient with me, also trying to learn django.

I have the following codes:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'apartment')
```

and

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<head>
    <title>Browse Rooms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/browse_rooms.css' %}">
</head>
{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h2 class="mb-4"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Browse Rooms</h2>
        <div class="row">
            {% for apartment in apartments %}
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        {% if apartment.image %}
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ apartment.image.url }}"
                                 alt="Profile Image">
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ apartment.address }}, {{ apartment.city }}, {{ apartment.state }} {{ apartment.zipcode }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Price: ${{ apartment.price }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Bedrooms: {{ apartment.bedrooms }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Bathrooms: {{ apartment.bathrooms }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Move-in Date: {{ apartment.move_in_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
                            <a href="{% url 'apartment_detail' apartment.id %}" class="btn btn-primary"><i
                                    class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> View Details</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                               onclick="addToFavorites({{ apartment.id }})"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> Add to
                                Favorites</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% empty %}
                <p>No apartments found.</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to search on web how to implement this function but there are many methods and i don't understand the logic behind cause they are all different.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You only share a model and a template?

Comment: That's all i got, starting from a new model, i have the template but i don't know how to create a view for it, also i think i need javascript for it...

Comment: Yes, you'll need to post what the js code for "addToFavorites" is. Where did that code come from?

Comment: I don't have any, sorry for the confusion... i hope you could help me and i will modify the html code. I'm not an expert :(